# Bash script to replace all hyphens with dots in filenames

Tags: bash

I want a script that replaces hyphens with dots in dates represented in filenames as XXXX-XX-XX. So something called 2019-09-05 moves to 2019.09.05. I've looked at other solutions for similar problems and have come up with the following:

```
for file in *-*-*; do
    mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed s/*-*-*/*.*.*/)"
done
```

But all this does is replace all the files separated by hyphens with a single file called *.*.*. I'm not fully sure how bash regex works or how I need to format the output side of it to make it work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a pure bash environment and you don't mind for portability, you can use [parameters expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
for file in *-*-*; do
  mv "${file}" "${file//-/.}"
done
```

If you still want to use sed, just replace what you did with `sed -e "s/-/./g"`

EDIT:
As @pjh said, `*-*-*` used in the `for` statement will check for files starting with hyphen (`-`), too.

Because of that, it is better to avoid confusion using `mv -- "${file}" "${file//-/.}"` instead of simply `mv "${file}" "${file//-/.}"`, making the script more robust.

Comment: @pjh This is true for every answer given here, but OP asked a solution for files that start always with numbers...

Comment: It's best to write code that makes as few assumptions as possible about what characters may appear in filenames.  Requirements change, and code gets copied (particularly from StackOverflow!).  The solution code partly follows that principle because it uses quotes that are not necessary if filenames are of the form YYYY-MM-DD.  I've found it best to completely follow the principle.

Comment: You are absolutely right, and I like this kind of thinking, but we are here to make practical solutions for just a piece of the problem, not the whole thing, otherwise we should check other things like free memory and (maybe with a regex) for the filenames themselves... E.G. `qwe-asd-zxc` will match as well and this is not what OP asked... There are just so many things to think about that you cannot follow them all for every reply here in SO

Answer (score 3):

To retain the three pieces you need to *capture* them with parentheses and then use backreferences (`\1`, `\2`, `\3`) them in the replacement string. Also `sed` expects a regular expression so `*` becomes `.*`.

```
for file in *-*-*; do
    mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed -r 's/(.*)-(.*)-(.*)/\1.\2.\3/')"
done
```

Alternatively, you could just replace dashes with dots and ignore the stuff in between.

```
for file in *-*-*; do
    mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed 's/-/./g')"
done
```

A even simpler way is to do the replacement with bash syntax rather than sed.

```
for file in *-*-*; do
    mv "$file" "${file//-/.}"
done
```